# How to identify the cause of my SIGTrap Crash?

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crash-reports

My team recently launched an app for which there's been quite a lot of SIGTRAP Crashes. Previously I've found these relatively simple to fix as it was a matter of finding a poor force cast or an implicitly unwrapped optional being set to nil in the offending function. This time though I can't find anything of the sort. My best guess is that maybe one of the `TimeBlock` objects or its properties is nil due to a calendar error.

Our app is a meeting organizer that shows the user their native iOS calendar events in terms of FreeTime, Conflicts and Meeting `TimeBlocks`. I have access to the calendars of several users who have crashed.

**Apple SigTrap Definition**

> Swift code will terminate with this exception type if an unexpected
>   condition is encountered at runtime such as:
>
> - a non-optional type with a nil value
> - a failed forced type conversion

**Crashing Function**

```
    /**
    Updates the conflictHours and meetingHours according to the timeblocks
    it is used as quick light reference to the button
 */
func updateTimeHours(timeblocks : [Timeblock]) {
    for timeblock in timeblocks {
        switch timeblock {
        case is MeetingTimeblock:
            for i in timeblock.startHour...timeblock.endHour {
                self.meetingHours[i] = true
            }
            break
        case is ConflictTimeblock:
            for i in timeblock.startHour...timeblock.endHour {
                self.conflictsHours[i] = true
            }
            break
        default: break
        }
    }
    updateButtonByOffset(offset: self.scrollTimeline.contentOffset.x)
}
```

**Call of Crashing Function**

```
    /**
    This function inits the variables and button layout according to the timeblocks
 */
func handleTimeblocksDependantComponents() {
    buttonLayout()
    guard Scheduler.sharedInstance.timelines.count > SharedGlobals.Calendar.TODAY_INDEX else {
        return
    }
    updateTimeHours(timeblocks : (Scheduler.sharedInstance.timelines[SharedGlobals.Calendar.TODAY_INDEX].timeblocks))
}
```

**SetHeaderHeight**

```
/**
 Adjusts the height of the header depending on whether there are hosted meetings or 
 meeting VIP's or not.
*/
private func setHeaderHeight() {
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView
    let hostedMeetings = OverviewInteractor.getHostedMeetings(dayIndex: SharedGlobals.Calendar.SELECTED_DAY)
    let vips = OverviewInteractor.getVIPS(dayIndex: SharedGlobals.Calendar.SELECTED_DAY)

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    if let headerView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView {
        var height = 360.0
        if(vips.count == 0) { height -= 80.0 }
        if(hostedMeetings.count == 0) { height -= 80.0 }
        headerView.frame.size.height = CGFloat(height)
    }
    self.tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

**TimeBlock Definition**

```
// The Timeblock parent class. It simply holds a start and end time and provides its own duration. Not to be used as such
public class Timeblock {
    public let startTime: Date
    public let endTime: Date

    /// Returns the hour the Timeblock starts, in current timezone
    public var startHour: Int {
        get {
            return Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: startTime)
        }
    }

    /// Returns the hour the Timeblocks ends, in current timezone
    public var endHour: Int {
        get {
            return Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: endTime)
        }
    }

    /// Returns the minutes the Timeblocks starts
    public var startMinutes: Int {
        get {
            return Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: startTime)
        }
    }

    /// Returns the minutes the Timeblocks ends
    public var endMinutes: Int {
        get {
            return Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: endTime)
        }
    }

    /**
        Initialises the instance with a start and end time
        - Parameters:
            - startTime: The start time of the timeblock
            - endTime: The end time of the timeblock
    */
    public init(startTime: Date, endTime: Date) {
        self.startTime = startTime
        self.endTime = endTime
    }

    /**
        Provides the Timeblock's duration in the form of a DateInterval
        - warning: Only available on iOS 10.0 and up
        - returns: A DateInterval of the duration of the Timeblock
    */
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    public func getTimeInterval() -> DateInterval {
        return DateInterval(start: self.startTime, end: self.endTime)
    }

    /**
        Provides the Timeblock's duration in the form of a `Double` (number of seconds)

        - returns: The number of seconds that this Timeblock goes on for
    */
    public func getDuration() -> Double {
        return self.endTime.timeIntervalSince(self.startTime)
    }

}
```

**Crash Report**

> Incident Identifier: 98D4F477-C57B-4767-B957-E9EA2E0EE3EA
>   CrashReporter Key:   0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 Hardware
>   Model:      undefined Process:             xxxxxxx [784] Identifier:
>   com.xxx.xxx.xx.xxxxxxx Version:             4.0.3 Code Type:
>   arm64
>
> Date/Time:           Sun Dec 24 2017 09:55:23 GMT+0000 (GMT) Launch
>   Time:         Invalid Date OS Version:          undefined 11.0.3
>   (15A432) Report Version:      105
>
> Exception Type:  SIGTRAP Exception Subtype: undefined
>
> Thread 0 name: Thread 0 Crashed: 0   CallIn
>   0x0000000102c224e4 specialized
>   TimelineHeader.updateTimeHours(timeblocks:) (TimelineHeader.swift:0) 1
>   CallIn                             0x0000000102c20af0
>   TimelineHeader.handleTimeblocksDependantComponents()
>   (TimelineHeader.swift:0) 2   CallIn
>   0x0000000102c7a28c specialized
>   MeetingTableViewController.tableView(*:viewForHeaderInSection:)
>   (TimelineHeader.swift:78) 3   CallIn
>
>   0x0000000102c75d54 @objc
>   MeetingTableViewController.tableView(*:viewForHeaderInSection:)
>   (MeetingTableViewController.swift:0) 4   UIKit
>      0x000000018d1157d8 -[UITableView _delegateViewForHeaderInSection:]
>   (UIKit) 5   UIKit                              0x000000018d11def0
>   **96-[UITableView _sectionHeaderView:withFrame:forSection:floating:reuseViewIfPossible:willDisplay:]_block_invoke
>   (UIKit) 6   UIKit                              0x000000018cdf1a14
>   +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] (UIKit) 7   UIKit                            0x000000018d11dc60 -[UITableView
>   _sectionHeaderView:withFrame:forSection:floating:reuseViewIfPossible:willDisplay:]
>   (UIKit) 8   UIKit                              0x000000018cfc6c04
>   -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForExistingHeadersAndFooters] (UIKit) 9   UIKit                               0x000000018cfc1070 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations]
>   (UIKit) 10  UIKit                              0x000000018cfc0944
>   -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] (UIKit) 11  UIKit                               0x000000018cfa8448 -[UITableView *endCellAnimationsWithContext:]
>   (UIKit) 12  UIKit                              0x000000018cfa46e4
>   -[UITableView endUpdates] (UIKit) 13  CallIn                           0x0000000102c761a4 MeetingTableViewController.setHeaderHeight()
>   (MeetingTableViewController.swift:398) 14  CallIn
>
>      0x0000000102c7a7c8 specialized closure #1 in
>   MeetingTableViewController.refreshTable(*:)
>   (MeetingTableViewController.swift:513) 15  CallIn
>
>      0x0000000102c7aacc partial apply for closure #1 in
>   MeetingTableViewController.refreshTable(_:)
>   (MeetingTableViewController.swift:0) 16  CallIn
>
>      0x0000000102cd17f0 thunk for @callee_owned () -> ()
>   (LoginPageViewController.swift:0) 17  libdispatch.dylib
>
>   0x000000018327ea54 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
>   (libdispatch.dylib) 18  libdispatch.dylib
>
>   0x000000018327ea14 _dispatch_client_callout (libdispatch.dylib) 19 
>   libdispatch.dylib                  0x000000018328b698
>   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp (libdispatch.dylib) 20  CoreFoundation                    0x00000001838aa544
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** (CoreFoundation) 21  CoreFoundation                     0x00000001838a8120 __CFRunLoopRun
>   (CoreFoundation) 22  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001837c7e58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (CoreFoundation) 23 
>   GraphicsServices                   0x0000000185674f84 GSEventRunModal
>   (GraphicsServices) 24  UIKit
>   0x000000018ce4767c UIApplicationMain (UIKit) 25  CallIn
>      0x0000000102c02c08 main (AppDelegate.swift:18) 26  libdyld.dylib
>      0x00000001832e456c start (libdyld.dylib)

Comment: can you post the `MeetingTableViewController.setHeaderHeight()` method?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I've updated the question to include it.

Comment: I think that the issue is related to the fact that you are modifying the header height externally, you need to change this and return the height in the `heightForHeaderInSection` method

Comment: I think the setHeaderHeight() is modifying the header view height of the table, no the header from the sections

Comment: Can you show the definition of Timeblock as I can't see if that has any optionals.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Updated the question with the definition, there's no optionals in there.

Comment: Are the self.meetingHours and self.conflictsHours setup correct in that you are never trying to access by an index (i) that doesn't exist?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth They're set to have a fixed length of 24 elements. I've been looking through user events to see if there's any errors in their calendar giving them a 25+ hour clock but haven't found anything so far. I'm not sure it's the culprit as I'd expect to see an index out of bounds error rather than SigTrap if this was the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reproduction**

This was caused by the index being messed up by `Timeblock.startHour` and `Timeblock.endHour` being `Int` values. After looking at our users calendars I noticed all of them had meetings that ended at midnight.

So for a meeting that went on between 5PM to Midnight we'd get the following happening.

`for i in timeblock.startHour...timeblock.endHour`
became
`for i in 0...17`

This would give quite a precise error telling me I couldn't iterate backwards once I reproduced the crash which unfortunately didn't appear in the crash report which was a bit misleading.

**Fix**

We had capped the times that create the `timeblock.endHour` property so `> 0:00` of the next day was changed to `23:59` to prevent this. The fix was simply applying the cap to `>= 0:00` so a meeting ending at midnight isn’t treated as a multi-day meeting.

A future refactor will likely be to set the end hour for all times that end on the hour to the previous hour as technically if your meeting ends at 11:00am you still have the hour free. I'd also like to handle this all within the `Timeblock` object rather than filter the argument used to create it.